# Javascript format date dd/mm/yyyy mala aproximación

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente código el cual imprime la fecha 31/09/2021 en vez de 01/10/2021 :

```js
let d = new Date('2021-10-01');
let year = d.getFullYear();

let month = d.getMonth() + 1;
if(month <= 9)
    month = '0'+month;

let day= d.getDate()+1;
if(day <= 9)
    day = '0'+day;

var prettyDate = day+'/'+ month +'/'+ year;
console.log(prettyDate);
```

Por qué hace mal la aproximación? si 31/09/2021 no existe, septiembre sólo tiene 30 días...

Comment: La fecha que se imprime es **02/10/2021**, que es el resultado de sumarle 1 mes y 1 día a **2021-10-01**, que es precisamente lo que hace la función.

Comment: @phpMyGuel quizás sea problema del navegador, pero me imprime esa fecha (31/09/2021)

Comment: @phpMyGuel hay que sumarle 1 porque comienzan desde cero

Comment: Si la fecha de la que partes es **2021-10-01** debería darte el ver lo que te digo. Un mes es un mes y un día es un día independientemente de la zona horaria.

Comment: Modifiqué tu pregunta para hacer tu código ejecutable y que puedas verlo.

Comment: @phpMyGuel lo ejecute e imprime lo que te digo 31/09/2021

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129177/discussion-between-user2820116-and-phpmyguel).

Answer (score 0):

Se solicionó cambiando los guiones por slashs en la fecha ingresada